# Call base inside overriden method

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

I know there are questions about calling the base method inside an overridden method such as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166234/do-any-oo-languages-support-a-mechanism-to-guarantee-an-overriden-method-will-ca). But what if an overridden method only calls the base class? Is this bad/good deign? It just seems odd, why override a method just to call the base anyway?

For example see:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    virtual public void Method1()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public class InheritingClass : BaseClass
{
    override public void Method1()
    {
        base.Method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: It serves no purpose and just clutters up the code, so get rid of it.

Comment: @DavidArno that's what I thought too, just making sure there wasn't a reason for it before I did so

Comment: In an ideal world, the app will be covered by unit tests, thus you could remove it, and when the tests all still passed, you'd know it wasn't needed. We don't always live in that ideal world though, so it was sensible to ask :)

Comment: The only reason I'd leave the code looking like the above would be if there was more code in the overridden method in the past, and it was removed, but could be viewed through old versions in the source control system. Leaving an artifact in the current code like this could signal to the dev today to view the file's history for the previous version of the method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But what if an overridden method only calls the base class? Is this bad/good design?

Bad *design*? No, rather bad implementation. It's misleading for the maintenance programmer. When I don't see an override then I *know* the base is called. An override tells me there is something different, even if the base is called in there as well.

---

**Requiring an override to call the base without a template is Bad Design**

[Referenced thread - most popular answser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/166277/38663)

My *initial* reaction to *the Scandinavian override model* is: CODING HORROR! It looks like I am forced to read all of that, and then more, to make sure the "sub-behavior" does not break my code and vice versa.

The [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) is a good way to express variable code within some larger code flow and ensure correct execution order.

In my experience it so typical for a subclass to have to know what base-declared methods to call, and in order. Take a heaping handful of sub classes all with the same cut-n-paste control structure, add 5 years of maintenance; now you understand why I prefer 101 proof [Wild Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Turkey_%28bourbon%29).

P.S. All that is one big reason why I rail against the over-use of `interface`s in lieu of `abstract` classes.

Comment: The over-use of interfaces in C# most likely comes from not wanting to shackle the implementer to that specific abstract base class. Using an interface allows the implementer to implement anther base class, and not just *that* specific abstract class. It depends a lot on the circumstances though. I find a good practice is to have both an `IFoo` interface and a `FooBase` class, which implements the `IFoo` interface, with abstract method-calls for the methods and auto-properties for the props. Maybe throw in a ctor as well.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, `virtual` methods, in base class, have very basic implementation. Even if we `override` the definition of `virtual` method in child class, we can still call the `virtual` method (with basic implementation) while it makes sense and does not affect the intended behavior of the `overridden` method in the child class.

For example, `BaseCalculator` does the real work. `Calculator` is decorating the `BaseCalculator` library by extending it.

```
public class BaseCalculator
{
    public virtual T Add<T>(T number01, T number02)
    {
        return number01 + number02;
    }
}

public class Calculator: BaseCalculator
{
    public override T Add<T>(T number01, T number02)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number01 + " | " + number02);
        var result = base.Add<int>(1, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: "+ result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Q: What if an overridden method only calls the base class?**

**A:** In your case, having a base class method as `virtual`, we need not to `override` it until we want to change its behavior.

**Q: Is this bad/good design?**

**A:** Yes, it could be bad design as it may clutter the source code file while we add unnecessary overrides.

**Q: It just seems odd, why override a method just to call the base anyway?**

**A:** `BaseCalculator` does the real work. `Calculator` is decorating the `BaseCalculator` library by extending it.

Hope, it helps!

Comment: I would make emphasis on -Don't override if you don't have to. Ex. right now I am creating a procedure where I have 2 possible objects to get the job done, they are mostly the same, I had originally an Interface, then realized they shared like 80% of the code, so I changed for an abstract class, leveraging virtual as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have eight slightly related virtual methods. Seven of them call the base class, with some action before and after and possibly changed arguments for the baseclass method. And by some coincidence, for the eighth method just calling the base class is exactly what’s needed.

In that case, not mentioning method #8 will always raise the suspicion that it was forgotten. So either you add it, commented out, with a comment saying that calling the baseclass has the desired effect, or you can add it calling the baseclass and nothing else. When surrounded by 7 similar methods, it’s fine.