# C# design to force the virtual method to be called from the override, or something similar

Tags: c#, design, inheritance, keywords

We can do something like this:

```
// in base class
protected virtual void Init(){
   //do stuff that all objects need to do
}

//in derived class
protected override void Init(){
   base.Init(); // if you forget this but it compiles all hell breaks loose
   //do derived stuff related to this object
}
```

I spent a good 15 minutes with a logic error because i simply forgot the base init call.

But there is no keyword to "demand" or contractually force the derived method to call the base equivalent. So if you forget, you're going to have a bad time in some cases where you need to call the base. Or other times where you call base and the derived class didn't need to because it overrides all the base values rather than some of them.

Is there a way to make this more robust/strict so such forgetfulness does not occur.

Comment: Do you call the base method first? Last? Somewhere in the middle? It’s... not necessarily a bad pattern - `base` exists in the first place after all - but it is rare. Rare enough that it never warranted the cost of complicating the language and its implementations.

Comment: There are cases where you actually want to replace the implementation outright and not call the base method.  Same is true of Java, C++, Ruby, Python, etc.  They all allow you to either explicitly call the base method, or not.  Not to mention, the question of when in the method you are trying to call base (before everything else, after everything else, or somewhere in the middle).

Comment: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/839601)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do any OO languages support a mechanism to guarantee an overriden method will call the base?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166234/do-any-oo-languages-support-a-mechanism-to-guarantee-an-overriden-method-will-ca)

Comment: I wonder if an event handler better fits your use case

Comment: @gnat as per the question i changed it not to really ask why but about if there was a better design option. Please read beyond the title ;)

Comment: @SebastianRedl im not really asking if languages support it, i ultimately asking if there is a design in which you can make it a requirement. Wish people read the full question to the end first. Your link does not really supply a solution for a design that would solve the problem.

Comment: You could write your program in Beta / gBeta, which has *prefix inheritance*. IOW, it is not the *overriding* method that calls `super`, it is the *overridden* method that calls `inner`. So, unless the overridden method explicitly calls the overriding method, the overriding method will never be executed. The overridden method can control exactly at what point the overridden method gets executed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag well this was more aimed at C# since i am using an engine that uses C# can't really change now :)

Comment: @WDUK I read the question and all the answers, your accusations notwithstanding.  akton's answer in my link gives you a solution to your actual question (enforce base behavior in overridable method call by using NVI or the template method pattern). Michael Borgwardt's answer gives you another alternative: Java has a tool that, with an annotation, can enforce this rule. C# has similar capabilities through [Roslyn static analyzers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers). So yes, your question is very much a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because same effect could already be achieved by a standard pattern of empty overridables.

If all of your non-sealed methods have empty body, it would not matter if they are called from overridden method. Use method template pattern to seal your implementation, and leave only empty methods exposed for override:

```
public sealed override void callMe() {
     before();
     overrideMe();
     after();
}

protected virtual void overrideMe() {
   // left empty to be optionally implemented in children
}
```

Seal methods with mandatory calls, and implementor won't be able to circumvent those.

Comment: And now, you've replaced one problem - the  base method not being called when it should - with a new problem: [the Fragile Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem. Any change to `callMe` risks breaking child classes, which not not be under your control. You've tightly coupled your base class to all current and future sub classes.

Comment: @DavidArno That problem wasn't freshly introduced by this change. It applied to changes in the base version of `Init` in the original problem statement just as much. To quote the Wikipedia page you linked to: "The fragile base class problem is a fundamental architectural problem of object-oriented programming systems".

Comment: @SebastianRedl, true, it is a fundamental problem with inheritance and thus with OO itself. However, the proposed solution here is a really good example of this problem in action. The OP's solution just risks changes to `init` affecting sub classes. Here though, the solution has this problem and now calls a protected method, deliberately coupling the base class to it's future sub classes, thus making things even more fragile. It is a truly awful solution and it is sad to see people upvoting this antipattern.

Comment: @DavidArno the goal here is to establish a compiler enforced contract of child-parent communication. It is pretty strict and obvious. Please suggest an example of parent class change that would break a child in a non-obvious manner.

Comment: I don't think that child breaking parent is better than parent breaking child. And the point about coupling applies to both original (init) and this (empty method) implementations.

Comment: @DavidArno: The frailty you're pointing at is irrelevant for OP's case where he wishes to _enforce_ proper usage in derived classes. He's not happy if it just builds, he's happy if the derived class does _exactly_ what its base class stipulates. If you wish to enforce this type of stipulations (which he does), and you've already created derived classes, then you either should no longer touch the base class (at least not its stipulations for derived classes), or accept the fact that you need to revisit your derived classes to ensure that your changed stipulations are still being followed.

Comment: @DavidArno: I could claim that any interface is similarly fragile. Any change you make to it is liable to break the classes implementing the interface. On principle, it's the exact same thing. But you need to consider that interfaces are intended _specifically because_ they are a set of enforced rules that need to be followed. A base class which hosts the public methods and forces its derived classes to implement protected override methods _inherently_ puts a joint responsibility on the base class and its derived classes. It's not a flaw if it's an explicit intention.

Comment: So is it safe to say there isn't really a way to design it in a more robust manner without some issues cropping up else where?

Comment: @WDUK, there is no way to avoid all existing problems with this kind of design. It is safe to say, that some caveats will always be present. However, such a statement holds no value being philosophically trivial. I beleive that in C# such protection is useful and justifies absence of Simula syntax.

Comment: @DavidArno "calls a protected method, deliberately coupling the base class to it's future sub classes" - I don't understand what you mean by that. What kind of problem do you see this producing?

Comment: @Flater, "*I could claim that any interface is similarly fragile*". Sure you could. You'd be wrong if you did though. Changing an interface will break the build for statically typed languages. That's the opposite of fragility. "*It's not a flaw if it's an explicit intention*". We are playing semantics now: yes, if one wants to be pedantic, it's not a flaw; it's negligence.

Comment: @DavidArno: You're completely ignoring the point that it's hypocritical to say that changing a base class leading to breaking a derived class is bad, but changing an interface leading to breaking an implementing class is good. OP is using his base class as an interface _with substance_. Having a derived class override a single method of a larger method stack (e.g. `DbContext.OnModelCreating`) is not inherently bad practice. If EF were to change how/when `OnModelCreating` is called, **of course** that is going to break existing derivations of `DbContext`. That is an inevitability.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, it means that changes to the implementation details of the base class can all too easily break code that depends on it. If you create a leaky abstraction like the example code here, you are no longer properly encapsulating those "inner workings", so they become coupled to those dependencies, rather than just those dependencies being coupled to the base class. The base class has both afferent and efferent couplings to its child classes. This is a bad thing.

Comment: @DavidArno: Just to point out the focus on what I'm disagreeing with: (1) I agree that it tightly couples the base and derived class. But that is exactly what the developer requests. It's done by design. It's not an unwanted side effect. (2) It is not an antipattern. You're simply not recognizing the valid use case for which this exists. (3) It is not an awful solution unless you're able to show an objectively better solution. Since you claim this problem is endemic to OO; that means that in the scope of OOP, the argument of frailty is irrelevant as _every_ OO approach suffers from it anyway.

Comment: @DavidArno: This is not the place to soapbox against OOP. Feel free to add an answer with an suitable alternate solution. Criticizing answers for problems that are endemic to the (OO) scope of the question is pointless (if you're already soaked, stop trying to hold the umbrella up), doubly so when not offering a counter solution that actually avoids the issue yet stays in scope of the asked question.

Comment: @Flater I agree. That’s why I’m avoiding soapboxing and instead I’m sticking to simple facts.

Comment: @DavidArno I still don't understand. What inner workings of the base class are exposed here? So far you've been extremely vague, claiming that this introduces additional coupling. But I just don't see it. What is the baseline code that we introduce additional coupling to? The only thing that I can see that might possibly be worrisome is the state of the base class when `overrideMe` is called. But I don't see that this is worse in this case than in any other variant of the "here's an object in some state" situation.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The problem with your request is that we work with simplified examples here, while "composition over inheritance" mainly solves issues that come with complexity. I don't think it's actually possible to explain it with 7 lines of code, let alone in this here comment box! Generally speaking though: The sub classes can depend on the base class _implementation_. That's _technically_ OK because it's the same object - but a change in your base class now has the possibility to break a sub class you don't even know.